# Error when using PowerShell to add DataSource to ComboBox

Tags: wpf, powershell, combobox

My goal is to have a viewable text that can say what I want and have the value of that text be used for the onchange event. However, I can't seem to get the datasource to attach to the combobox.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="WPFDomainUsersBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="288,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215" Height="23" Text="Domain Users"/>
...
...
...
#create a datatable to bind to our combobox
    $datatable = New-Object system.Data.DataTable
    #Define Columns
    $ColValue = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Value",([string])
    $ColText = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Text",([string])
    #add columns to datatable
    $datatable.columns.add($ColValue)
    $datatable.columns.add($ColText)

    #List option.
    $DomainUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter *
    ForEach($DUsers in $DomainUsers) {
        #$WPFDomainUsersBox.Items.Add($DUsers.SamAccountName)

        $datarow = $datatable.NewRow()
        #Enter data in the row
        $datarow.Value = $DUsers.SamAccountName
        $datarow.Text = $DUsers.SamAccountName
        #Add the row to the datatable
        $datatable.Rows.Add($datarow)
    }

    $WPFDomainUsersBox.Datasource = $datatable
```

I keep getting the following:

> The property 'Datasource' cannot be found on this object. Verify that
>   the property exists and can be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [WPF `ComboBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx)  has no property named "Datasource". It has an [`ItemsSource` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.110).aspx) that you can set to any `IEnumerable` like for example the `DataView` of a `DataTable`:

```
$WPFDomainUsersBox.ItemsSource = $datatable.DefaultView
```